# Copying frameworks into project?

Tags: iphone, xcode, openal

When attempting to copy a framework into the Frameworks folder of my project in Xcode, I get the error

> Could not copy /Developer/Platforms/.../Frameworks/OpenAL.framework to /Users/.../OpenAL.framework

I had accidentally copied the wrong framework with the same name into the project earlier and deleted it, but now I can't copy the correct one in?  How do I get totally rid of the wrong version before copying the appropriate version in?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a *new* framework for iPhone development. Instead, you should add an *existing* framework, and go find the framework in (for example) `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/`

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to copy OpenAL.framework into your project at all?  You don't need to copy a framework into your project directory to link against it, and OpenAL.framework is provided by the operating system (as you can tell from it being located under `/Developer`.)

Also, be aware that third-party frameworks aren't supported on iPhone, you can only use static libraries.  I mention this because you added the `iPhone` tag to your question, so I assume you're building an iPhone application.

Comment: Are you sure OpenAL isn't supported as a third-party framework?  It's used in the iPhone example Crash Landing from Apple's development site.

Comment: It's a framework shipped with the operating system.  You don't need to copy it into your application.